# PHP - Loop through all files in a directory, in reverse order

Tags: php

I am currently using this code to loop through each image in a folder:

```
$directory= "../images/uploads/*.jpg";
$images = glob( $directory );

foreach ($images as $image){
    $filename = $file = basename($image);
    echo("$image <br/>");
}
```

Each file is uploaded with an incremental ID number at the beginning so I need it to display these with the latest ID first. (Reverse alphabetical).

Is this possible to do?

Comment: [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) ?

Comment: A bit of research wouldn't go amiss! PHP has a whole manual chock full of function references.

Comment: Why you have there `$filename = $file = basename($image);`? It's in the loop, in both variables, $filename and $file you will have the latest image name.

Comment: Sorry, I did research it, I didn't type the correct words in to google though.

Comment: @panther No idea. I copied the code and modified it, Didn't even notice it to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) to do that:

```
$directory= "../images/uploads/*.jpg";
$images = glob( $directory );

foreach (array_reverse($images) as $image){
    $filename = $file = basename($image);
    echo("$image <br/>");
}
```